# Add additional args to cordova.exec function

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a question, I am using a plugin in cordova, but I need to pass 2 args, I want to know if this structure can be inside the exec function

I need add "[str2]"

```
cordova.exec(callback, function(err) {
        callback('Nothing to echo.');
    }, "Echo", "echo", [str], [str2]);
```

Android : I need add JSONArray args2

```
 public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, JSONArray args2,CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
    //..
        } catch (Exception e) {
          callbackContext.error("Error");
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I hope you can help me or understand a little better!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass any number of args in the array as shown below.

```
 cordova.exec(callback, function(err) {
    callback('Nothing to echo.');
 }, "Echo", "echo", [arg1, arg2, arg3,....]);
```

While accessing the code in android you do it as

```
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
    data1 = args.optString(0);
    data2 = args.optString(1);
    .
    .
    .
    } catch (Exception e) {
      callbackContext.error("Error");
    }
    return true;
}
return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped me and it was complete, the only thing I can add is that in Android I get the array in the following way:

public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args,CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {

  String name = args.getString(0);
  JSONArray state = args.getJSONArray(2);


} catch (Exception e) {
              callbackContext.error("Error al obtener los datos iniciales");
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

Answer (score 1):

args is an array, so if you need to have several parameters just put this parameters in the array instead of trying to add a second array containing only one element :

```
cordova.exec(callback, function(err) {
        callback('Nothing to echo.');
    }, "Echo", "echo", [str, str2]);
```

And then on the java side you get your strings by `args.optString(0)` and `args.optString(1)`